# BusyIndicator to datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

on click a button i load data to my datagrid

```
MySqlCommand cmd1m = new MySqlCommand("select * from table", conn);
DataTable dt1m = new DataTable();
dt1m.Load(cmd1m.ExecuteReader());
System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource source = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource();
source.DataSource = dt1m;
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = source;
```

namespace:

```
xmlns:wpf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit/extended"
```

and xaml:

```
<wpf:BusyIndicator Name="loading" IsBusy="False">
<DataGrid>...</DataGrid>
</<wpf:BusyIndicator>
```

but indicator not working, why? What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! Consider using a more apt description than "not working". What isn't working? How is it not working? What do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my WPF App I have created my own wait cursor class

```
public class WaitCursor: IDisposable
{
    private Cursor _previousCursor;

    public WaitCursor()
    {
        _previousCursor = Mouse.OverrideCursor;
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = _previousCursor;
    }
}
```

and call it like this

```
// Some code for which you do not want wait cursor
// ...

using(new WaitCursor())
{
    dataGrid1.ItemsSource = source;
}
```

Comment: In that case time required to perform your operation is very small. Look for some think like running a loop of very big number and surround it.

Comment: data load ~ 2-3 sec...its normal?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the **IsBusy="True"** in BusyIndicator will make it show the indicator.

In your case, Bind the **boolean** property to IsBusy and make it True while loading data. After loading completed make it to False.

Answer (score 0):

You should toggle the "IsBusy" property when performing actions.

```
    loading.IsBusy = true;
    // ... perform actions ...
    loading.IsBusy = false;
```

Comment: It's still common sense to be nice to people. 2nd, it is practically the same answer as @smhnkmr. It's in pseudo code, so don't expect it to work after copy-paste. It doesn't hurt to think a little bit.